Arrange the 15 dominoes so that the sum of the fractions in each row is 10
From a standard double-six set of dominoes remove the doubles (tiles with the same number at both ends), and the tiles that contain a blank.  Then the following 15 tiles remain:

These 15 tiles, regarded as fractions, are shown below in three rows such that the sum of each row is 2.5:

The goal of this puzzle is to arrange the 15 tiles in three rows of 5 tiles each so that the sum of the fractions in each row is 10. (You can use improper fractions, such as 4/3, 6/1, 3/2.)

Attributions:
The puzzle is from The Moscow Puzzles by BORIS A. KORDEMSKY.
The triangular grid of dominoes is a modified version of an image from the Wikipedia article on dominoes.

If I coded it correctly, there are 428 solutions.

@DanielMathias Consider $\frac{1}{2} =\frac{2}{4}=\frac{3}{6} $ and $\frac{2}{3}=\frac{4}{6}$ and $\frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{6}$. For each solution, by switching the equivalent dominoes, we could get 24  equivalent solutions. Therefore, if this puzzle has multiple solutions, the amount of all solutions must be the multiples of 24. But $\frac{428}{24}\approx 17.83$. Maybe there might be something wrong with your process?

@tToE Your solution does not permit such swapping of dominoes.

@DanielMathias You're right. I was wrong. I've realized my mistake after posting this comment. I should not swapping them in this way, because some of the equivalent dominoes are inside of the same equation.

Correction of earlier comment: there are 372 solutions.

@DanielMathias agreed, although some solutions will use the same five tiles in the same sequence, but with some flipped. For example (3/1 + 4/1 + 2/3 + 6/4 + 5/6) and (3/1 + 4/1 + 3/2 + 4/6 + 5/6).

@WeatherVane It works! Actually, by exchange $\frac{3}{2} + \frac{4}{1}$ of the first equation  and $\frac{5}{2} + \frac{3}{1}$ of the second equation, we can get another solution. And similarly, by exchange $\frac{4}{2} + \frac{4}{1}$ of the first equation  and $\frac{3}{1} + \frac{6}{2}$ of the second equation,  it works, too.

@tToE there are many such examples, giving 372 solutions.

I got a solution like this:

 $$ \begin{aligned} \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2} + \frac{4}{2} + \frac{6}{3} + \frac{4}{1} &= 10 \\[5pt] \frac{5}{6} + \frac{5}{2} + \frac{3}{1} + \frac{6}{2} + \frac{4}{6} &= 10 \\[5pt] \frac{4}{5} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{6}{1} + \frac{5}{3} + \frac{4}{3} &= 10 \\ \end{aligned} $$

 Let:
 $$ \begin{array}{ccccc} \frac{1}{2} & & & &  \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & & &  \\ \frac{1}{4} & \frac{2}{4} & \frac{3}{4}  & &  \\ \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{3}{5}  & \frac{4}{5} &  \\ \frac{1}{6} & \frac{2}{6} & \frac{3}{6}  & \frac{4}{6} &  \frac{5}{6} \\ \end{array} \quad\Rightarrow\quad \begin{array}{ccccc} \frac{1}{2} & & & &  \\ \frac{3}{1} & \frac{3}{2} & & &  \\ \frac{4}{1} & \frac{4}{2} & \frac{4}{3}  & &  \\ \frac{1}{5} & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{5}{3}  & \frac{4}{5} &  \\ \frac{6}{1} & \frac{6}{2} & \frac{6}{3}  & \frac{4}{6} &  \frac{5}{6} \\ \end{array} $$


My solution differs from tToE's by more than just switching equivalent dominoes:

 

